# Matplotlib with seaborn doesn't show cyrillic symbols

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, ubuntu-18.04

I try to create some plots and save as pdf:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
...
pp = PdfPages('filename.pdf')
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))
...
pp.savefig()
```

it working well on DO droplet with Ubuntu 18.04, but it doesn't show all cyrrilic symbols(title, labels) with no error or warning on another KVM machine with Ubuntu 18.04. Without line `sns.set_style("whitegrid")` it working the same on both machines.
Where I can start digging?

---

python= 3.6.9.

```
matplotlib==3.1.2
numpy==1.18.0
pandas==0.25.3
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.9.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This file](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/seaborn-whitegrid.mplstyle) is the predefined "whitegrid" style - it's probably the font definitions:

```
font.family: sans-serif
font.sans-serif: Arial, Liberation Sans, DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, sans-serif
```

You can probably [override `font.sans-serif`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html#overriding-elements-of-the-seaborn-styles) in a way that uses a font that has properly working cyrillics (maybe take a look at the `sns.axes_style()` output for the working configuration).

Comment: `sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'font.family': ['sans-serif'], 'font.sans-serif': ['DejaVu Sans']})` – works for me, thx.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark the answer as correct if you can. :)